# Python Submodules Not Found

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, git-submodules

I'm using virtualenv and I installed a package using pip "pip install libnmap". It was installed in successfully as seen below.

```
(env)danny@ubuntu:/opt/app/env$ ls -al local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libnmap/
total 144
drwxrwxr-x  4 danny danny  4096 Sep  8 23:08 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 danny danny  4096 Sep  8 23:14 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny  2896 Sep  8 23:05 diff.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny  4564 Sep  8 23:05 diff.pyc
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny   234 Sep  8 23:05 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny   427 Sep  8 23:08 __init__.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  2 danny danny  4096 Sep  8 23:05 objects
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny 25674 Sep  8 23:05 parser.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny 23246 Sep  8 23:05 parser.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  2 danny danny  4096 Sep  8 23:05 plugins
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny 23232 Sep  8 23:05 process.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny 23311 Sep  8 23:05 process.pyc
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny  1054 Sep  8 23:05 reportjson.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 danny danny  1810 Sep  8 23:05 reportjson.pyc
```

I can successfully import the module from my python console, but when I try to access the submodules they can't be found.

```
(env)danny@ubuntu:/opt/app/env$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libnmap
>>> libnmap
<module 'libnmap' from '/opt/app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libnmap/__init__.pyc'>
>>> dir(libnmap)
['__author__', '__builtins__', '__credits__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__license__', '__maintainer__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__']
>>> libnmap.process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Any ideas? I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

`process` is located in a separate file (`process.py`), and is not automatically imported when importing `libnmap` (checking `__init__.py`). You should add the following import to import process:

```
import libnmap.process
```